# Creating A Bootable Partition On USB Drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb-drive, iso

Hi have a USB drive with data already on it. Its 64Gb so unfortunately, Im not able to move/ transfer it easily.

Is there a way to make a new partition on the USB disk and make that new partition, the primary & bootable partition so that I can make it a bootable Ubuntu disk (for installation)?

Thanks,

Comment: Most of the tools, either erase entire drive, or use dd in background and erase the first GB or size of ISO including any partition table. But you probably can do it manually. IF you just want UEFI only: UEFI only USB key, just extract ISO ( 7 zip or similar) to FAT32 formated flash & set boot flag.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media If you want BIOS boot then install syslinux which is the standard boot loader used for installers.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't recomend but you can resize current partition and create, make bootable another one using GParted. This flash drive may not work correctly on some systems.